# Only attempt to login if the error code is 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have don't the API check if the token is expired. I have to make a GET call, if I got the `403`, error from the API, then I should re-login.

I attempted:

```
app.get = async (body) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let user = await user.findOne({
            where: {
                accountId: body.accountId
            }
        });

        if(user){
            body.accessToken = user.accessToken;
        } else {
            body.accessToken  = await app.login(); 
        }

        request(
        {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + body.accessToken
            },
            method: 'GET',
            uri: `${config.acs.url}${body.url}`,
            json: true
        }
        )

        .then((response) => {
            resolve(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // logger.info(error);

            if(error.statusCode == 403){
                body.accessToken  = await app.login(); <<------------- 
                app.get(body);
            }

            reject(error);
        });

    });

}
```

---

I don't know how else to avoid this error.

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in an `async` function

I already have

```
app.get = async (body) => { ...
```

I need to re-login only when I get the 403 code in the error block.

How do I re-structure my code to achieve what I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function used in the `Promise` is not an `async` function

Try this snippet

```
app.get = async (body) => {
    let resolve, reject;
    const promise = new Promise((re, rj) => {
        resolve = re;
        reject = rj;
    });

    let user = await user.findOne({
        where: {
            accountId: body.accountId
        }
    });

    if(user){
        body.accessToken = user.accessToken;
    } else {
        body.accessToken  = await app.login(); 
    }

    request(
    {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + body.accessToken
        },
        method: 'GET',
        uri: `${config.acs.url}${body.url}`,
        json: true
    }
    )

    .then((response) => {
        resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(async (error) => {
        // logger.info(error);

        if(error.statusCode == 403){
            body.accessToken  = await app.login(); <<------------- 
            app.get(body);
        }

        reject(error);
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks-you let me try

Comment: I still getting this `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: Can you please your answer for typo ?

Comment: I updated the snippet. can you try it now